# Reset button killed my control pad

Tags: ps3, controllers

While not paying attention, I accidentally reset the new controller for our PlayStation.

Now, when I connect it with the cable, it displays the message 'unknown USB device connected'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: So to clarify, you try bluetooth pairing it, and it says unknown USB device? If its a new controller, sounds like you should just be taking it back to the store for a replacement.

Comment: I say new its a couple of months old. The whole pad is dead, it doesnt light up, no response from ps button & i get the error message when i connect with the cable